# Working with pixels and argb

Tags: android

I have a loop that goes until `i < pixels.lenth` when `pixels = bitmap.getpixels(..)`.
Now i have this code inside my loop:

```
int argb = 0;
argb += ((pixels[x] >> 24) & 0xff); // alpha 
argb += (pixels[x] & 0xff);         // blue
argb += ((pixels[x] & 0xff) << 8);  // green
argb += ((pixels[x] & 0xff) << 16); // red
pixels[x] = argb;
```

The problem is that the image becomes *gray* and *bold* (can add a picture if anyone needs), instead of remaining normal. Can anyone help me?
Thanks a lot

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: what makes an image _bold_?

Comment: Your code sets the red, green and blue channels to the value of the blue channel (creating a grayscale image) and adds the value of the alpha channel (0 - 255) to this color. I think the last part is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You're shifting in the wrong order.  It should be:

```
int argb = 0;
int alpha = ((pixels[x] >> 24) & 0xff); // alpha 
int blue = (pixels[x] & 0xff);         // blue
int green = ((pixels[x] >> 8 )& 0xff) ;  // green
int red = ((pixels[x] >> 16) & 0xff); // red
pixels[x] = alpha << 24 + red << 16 + green << 8 + blue
```